# my ionic app delays before displaying background image

Tags: css, ionic-framework

i am building a mobile app with ionic, I want to give the app a background image so i had to style it in the variable.scss. Here is the code

```
ion-content {
    --background: #fff url("https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/1/80/dweUEj.jpg") no-repeat center center / cover;
}
```

Now my problem is that when the page loads, it shows a white background for like 3-5 seconds before displaying the background picture, is there a way i can make the background image to load as soon as the page is loaded without the with background

Comment: You can prefetch the image, move that to the top of your CSS or load the image within the page also,

Comment: how can i prefetch the image

Comment: download image and use it from assets folder.

Comment: i did that and its still the same except the time is now shorter